# Where can I get replacement battery connectors for old Lego Duplo Train?

Tags: trains, electronics, repair, duplo

I have the same Duplo Train that Pieterjan posted a picture and video of in September ('*[Old Lego duplo train not working on batteries](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/16598/3631)*'). In my case, it is clear that the battery connectors are corroded due to leaked batteries, and some have snapped as I removed them to clean them. Any idea where I might be able to buy replacements?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the contacts seem to be made specifically for [this model of Duplo Train](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=7148#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), I think an exact fitting off-the-shelf version likely doesn't exist. You could buy sheet metal of the same material and thickness, then try to cut and bend it to the right shape - or [buy another](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2961&idColor=6#T=S&C=6&O=%7B%22color%22:6,%22iconly%22:0%7D) (possibly otherwise broken) Duplo Train of the same type ([or in red](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2961&idColor=6#T=S&C=5&O=%7B%22color%22:%225%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)) to scavenge the connectors in used but official condition.