# DUPLO train engine base part# 28743 engine is not working

Tags: shopping, trains, duplo

I've went through all of the steps here:

[How to disassemble the propulsion wheels of the LEGO/DUPLO train engine base part# 28743 drivetrain?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/13425/how-to-disassemble-the-propulsion-wheels-of-the-lego-duplo-train-engine-base-par)

which was a great learning exercise but unfortunately it seems like the actual motor itself has kicked the bucket. I can hear it activating when I try to push start it and kick it off from Bluetooth. It even works for a half a second.

Any idea where you can get a spare or even people who have been able to go in and fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Bricklink is often the best place to find individual LEGO and Duplo parts.  The [28743c01 "Duplo, Train Locomotive Base Push & Go Motor"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=28743c01#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:11,%22iconly%22:0%7D) is currently available 18 times from $17.04 to $53.99.  This is perfect if you just want the one part and you don't want to deal with other new parts.

Bricklink also has new-in-the-box sets that include this part such as the [10874-1 Steam Train](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10874-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) for $41.08.  Getting some extra parts and having it all be new-in-the-box sounds like a better deal to me.  This motor was in a total of 3 sets, so you may prefer one of the other two Duplo trains that have this part.