# Duplo train engine base part - replacement DC motor - which part to buy?

Tags: repair, duplo, replacement-parts

I have two Duplo train base parts, one that works, one that I want to repair, as it does not work (connects via Bluetooth, but in the end motor does not move). I disassembled that and figured out the motor does not work, even when I apply 5V manually to plus and minus terminals (on the other hand I can make motor moved that way). The motor shows "open line" resistivity, in contrast to around 10 Ohms in case of working motor. So it is broken (likely the wire has burned inside the motor and hence the open line).

Question: **what motor should I buy for the replacement so that it fits?** It is a relatively new part, so these "must" still be manufactured. The motor has no brand or marking on it whatsoever except for R 033K, which did not help me in any way.

There is a [DUPLO train engine base part# 28743 engine is not working](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18429/duplo-train-engine-base-part-28743-engine-is-not-working)  but I do not want to buy entire part, just the motor.

[image: motor]

[image: parts]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have that DUPLO part handy, but this certainly looks like a standard type 130 toy motor:

[image: Type 130 motor photo]

These are available at many online electronics parts stores. Before you order, you'll likely want to confirm with the specific datasheet that the size of the motor matches yours. Here's an example datasheet that you could check against:

[image: Type 130 datasheet]

Comment: Interesting information, thanks. I wonder whether it's possible to replace the original motor with one that runs better from NiMH rechargeable? (i.e., 4.8V power source rather than 6V)

Comment: I googled the 130 motors, there are different motors with same dimensions. They differ in electric properties so it might be possible to alter that.

Comment: I ok'd the answer as this motor looks identically and it fits the dimensions shown above. Thanks!

Comment: I checked that you cannot any motor in there. If the motor takes too much current the drive electronics will interpret this as "train hit the obstacle lets stop". So it cannot be very different from the original one.

Comment: Hmm. All of the LEGO motors used 12v motors for durability or the replacement motor is rated at a similar voltage or different brand/company of the motors?

Comment: I see no serious rating on the motor.  In the end I fixed the original motor, but I still have to research replacements, as the repaired original motor performs unevenly to an other exemplar of original motor that I posses.

Comment: @Repairer, What could check the voltage? Is that 4.5 or so?

Tsukasa